# How do I stop code running when a form isn't submitted?

Tags: php, forms

I'm a real noob with PHP, so here' goes.

I have a script to edit a file with a form in it for what to put in the file, but every time I go to the page, it runs the script and clears the file before I put it in.

Also, how do I get it to submit to other pages, not just the page I did?

```
<?php

$ourFileName = $_GET['page'];
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_POST['stuff'];
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $stringData);
fclose($ourFileHandle);

?>

<form action="edit.php?page=index.html" method="post">
<textarea name="stuff" rows="10" cols="50" wrap="virtual" maxlength="300"></textarea>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the file managing code inside an `if (isset $_POST['stuff']) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`a+` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for your second argument.

> Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Also, using a GET param to open a file leaves you open to all sorts of vulnerabilities, such as [directory traversal attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal), and writing to your existing PHP files (which in turn could let a malicious user do anything PHP can do).

You should also make sure those variables are set before accessing them (and therefore opening the file and writing needlessly).

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) AND isset($_POST['stuff'])) { ... }
```

To submit to other pages, change your `form`'s `action` attribute to point to the new page.

Comment: It worked, but stack overflow has me wait six minutes before I can give you the correct answer.  In the meantime, how do you have the GET not have those queries while still working?  I was thinking somehow get the variable from the PHP in there.  I understand what you said about the vunerabilities; it's just part of a larger script that's password protected.

Comment: @IceCat `how do you have the GET not have those queries while still working?` Can you please elaborate on that, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I don't want it to have to have the query included in where I'm using the POST method in the HTML.

Comment: @IceCat OK, just remove it from the HTML `<form action="edit.php" method="post">`.

Comment: i just figured it out.  I put the whole form in the PHP with echo and then removed the action.  Thanks for your help!